# Selecting records overlapping with a given time range

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have the following table:

```
id  |   value   |   start_time  |   stop_time
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1   |   value1  |   06:00:00    |   11:00:00
2   |   value2  |   12:00:00    |   13:00:00
```

I need to select records whose time range overlap with 05:00–11:30. That means the record to be returned is row 1.

I tried using a query like this but it fails when the given time range crosses midnight. Perhaps it's impossible to do it without involving the date.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 
(
    (start_time >= '05:00:00' AND stop_time <= '11:30:00') ||
    (start_time >= '05:00:00' AND start_time <= '05:00:00') ||
    (start_time <= '05:00:00' AND stop_time >= '11:30:00') ||
    (stop_time >= '11:30:00' AND stop_time <= '05:00:00')
)
```

I'm thinking of enumerating all the minutes for the given time range and filtering using `BETWEEN` but there may be a better solution.

Comment: Could you show us your `BETWEEN` query?

Comment: @Dave, which data type are you using for the `start_time` and `stop_time` fields in this table?

Comment: I second marcio's and alex's -- Please post your SQL command and the data structure of the table as well. Additional table data and expected results will also be great. :)

Comment: Please don't tag your question titles. We already have tags.

Answer (score 0):

Dave,

The easiest way which i can see for you to achieve the desired result will be to use 'TIME' type for `start_time` and 'stop_time` fields. 
Then you can select like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `YOUR_TABLE_NAME_HERE` WHERE `start_time` > '05:00:00' AND `stop_time` < '11:30:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

Every range will need to be represented with a conditional, like so:

```
IF(start_time < stop_time, start_time >= '05:00:00' AND stop_time <= '11:30:00', start_time <= '05:00:00' AND stop_time >= '11:30:00')
```